How to change the stacking order of agents in a 2D view of a custom agent population?
In AnyLogic, I have a custom agent called 'Slab'. I've created an agent population using this agent, where an event creates a 'Slab' agent every 3 minutes, labeled as S0, S1, S2, and so on. When these slabs stack, I can control the stacking order by setting the z-value so that the later generated agent, S2, appears on top of the earlier generated agent, S0. However, in the 2D view, S0 still appears on top. How can I make S2 display above S0 in the 2D view?
anylogic 2D and 3D view

I found this help link on the AnyLogic official website, but it doesn't solve my issue, the function requires parameter of type MarkupShape, but my agent doesn't extend from MarkupShape.

I found that if I instantly generate all the required agents before showing the presentation, and adjust the order of agents within the population by using goToPopulation(), it works well. However, if I generate one every few minutes, I cannot achieve the desired effect. Nevertheless, the reality is that I need to generate one at intervals.my code



You need to call agent.presentation, this returns the markup shape.
For example:
main.presentation.remove(main.slabPopulation.get(0).presentation);
main.presentation.add(main.slabPopulation.get(0).presentation); // re-includes at the top

If you want to control this from the event, use this code in the event (assuming it sits on Main):
Slab newSlab = add_SlapPopulation(); // create new slab
presentation.remove(newSlab .presentation);
presentation.add(newSlab .presentation); // add to top in 2D


Thanks for Benjamin's reply. When I tried to use presentation.add(slab.presentation), I got an error message Top-level presentation group can't be added to any other group! Please use ShapeEmbeddedObjectPresentation class if needed..  I'm not sure what this means. My AnyLogic version is 8.8.1.

Try playing with ((Agent)myShape.getPresentable()).getPresentationShape() and Agent.getOwnerShape() . One of them should do the trick. Not at my machine so can't try it out. If in doubt, just add the agents in the order that you want them shown in 2D, this is the easiest approach by far
